# Errai 4.0 Beta 3 give this error "Encountered error when looking up JsType providers"

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I am getting this error in chrome console while debugging using Eclipse and SDBG. Beside this error, the web app and page is functioning well.

Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

[SyncBeanManager] Encountered error when looking up JsType providers for my.devs.web.client.local.page.Create

Where Create is

```
@Page
@Templated
public class Create extends Composite {
...
}
```

Full error:

```
13:05:49 FINE [Dash] Display create complaint form
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [Navigation] Navigating to Create at url: Create
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [SyncBeanManager] Looking up beans for my.devs.web.client.local.page.Create
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [SyncBeanManager] Encountered error when looking up JsType providers for my.devs.web.client.local.page.Create
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : lai_g$(...).getProviders is not a function
    at Unknown.TypeError: lai_g$(Unknown@-1)
    at Unknown.Xfi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@21:82497)
    at Unknown.egi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@27:82593)
    at Unknown.dgi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@15:82584)
    at Unknown.bgi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@22:82566)
    at Unknown.cgi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@26:82572)
    at Unknown.agi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@24:82553)
    at Unknown.Xgi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@31:82860)
    at Unknown.PGi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@31:91245)
    at Unknown.pDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@30:90073)
    at Unknown.qDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:90086)
    at Unknown.sDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:90099)
    at Unknown.rDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:90091)
    at Unknown.gDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@10:89962)
    at Unknown.k0i_g$(erraiapp-0.js@24:61969)
    at Unknown.l0i_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:61963)
    at Unknown.t0i_g$(erraiapp-0.js@24:62021)
    at Unknown.lambda_0_g$(erraiapp-0.js@27:103)
13:05:49 FINE [SyncBeanManager] Looked up 1 beans: [[type=my.devs.web.client.local.page.Create, qualifiers=[@Default, @Any]]]
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINEST [TemplateUtil] <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h1 class="text-inverse">Test Create</h1>
        <br> <br> <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Create</a>
    </div>
</div>
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINER [TemplateUtil] Searching template for fields.
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [Create] Create construct ...
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [Create] Create constructed ...
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [Dash] Dash page hiden!
```

I am also getting another similar error but for LifecycleListenerRegistrar

```
[SyncBeanManager] Encountered error when looking up JsType providers for org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.lifecycle.api.LifecycleListenerRegistrar

> ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [Dash] Display create complaint form
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [Navigation] Navigating to Create at url: Create
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [SyncBeanManager] Looking up beans for my.devs.web.client.local.page.Create
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [SyncBeanManager] Encountered error when looking up JsType providers for my.devs.web.client.local.page.Create
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : lai_g$(...).getProviders is not a function
    at Unknown.TypeError: lai_g$(Unknown@-1)
    at Unknown.Xfi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@21:82497)
    at Unknown.egi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@27:82593)
    at Unknown.dgi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@15:82584)
    at Unknown.bgi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@22:82566)
    at Unknown.cgi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@26:82572)
    at Unknown.agi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@24:82553)
    at Unknown.Xgi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@31:82860)
    at Unknown.PGi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@31:91245)
    at Unknown.pDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@30:90073)
    at Unknown.qDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:90086)
    at Unknown.sDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:90099)
    at Unknown.rDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:90091)
    at Unknown.gDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@10:89962)
    at Unknown.k0i_g$(erraiapp-0.js@24:61969)
    at Unknown.l0i_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:61963)
    at Unknown.t0i_g$(erraiapp-0.js@24:62021)
    at Unknown.lambda_0_g$(erraiapp-0.js@27:103)
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [SyncBeanManager] Looked up 1 beans: [[type=my.devs.web.client.local.page.Create, qualifiers=[@Default, @Any]]]
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINEST [TemplateUtil] <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h1 class="text-inverse">Test Create</h1>
        <br> <br> <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Create</a>
    </div>
</div>
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINER [TemplateUtil] Searching template for fields.
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [Create] Create construct ...
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [Create] Create constructed ...
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [Dash] Dash page hiden!
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [SyncBeanManager] Looking up beans for org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.lifecycle.api.LifecycleListenerRegistrar
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [SyncBeanManager] Encountered error when looking up JsType providers for org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.lifecycle.api.LifecycleListenerRegistrar
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : lai_g$(...).getProviders is not a function
    at Unknown.TypeError: lai_g$(Unknown@-1)
    at Unknown.Xfi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@21:82497)
    at Unknown.egi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@27:82593)
    at Unknown.dgi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@15:82584)
    at Unknown.bgi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@22:82566)
    at Unknown.cgi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@26:82572)
    at Unknown.agi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@24:82553)
    at Unknown.Xgi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@31:82860)
    at Unknown.oji_g$(erraiapp-0.js@12:83032)
    at Unknown.NDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@20:90266)
    at Unknown.JFi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@24:90841)
    at Unknown.n_i_g$(erraiapp-0.js@16:91489)
    at Unknown.m_i_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:91449)
    at Unknown.uDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@27:90119)
    at Unknown.mDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@12:89902)
    at Unknown.YDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@24:90353)
    at Unknown.dhi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@17:82919)
    at Unknown.PGi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@223:91245)
    at Unknown.pDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@30:90073)
    at Unknown.qDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:90086)
    at Unknown.sDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:90099)
    at Unknown.rDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:90091)
    at Unknown.gDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@10:89962)
    at Unknown.k0i_g$(erraiapp-0.js@24:61969)
    at Unknown.l0i_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:61963)
    at Unknown.t0i_g$(erraiapp-0.js@24:62021)
    at Unknown.lambda_0_g$(erraiapp-0.js@27:103)
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [SyncBeanManager] Looked up 1 beans: [[type=org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.lifecycle.impl.LifecycleListenerRegistrarImpl, qualifiers=[@Default, @Any]]]
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [SyncBeanManager] Looking up beans for org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.lifecycle.api.LifecycleListenerRegistrar
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [SyncBeanManager] Encountered error when looking up JsType providers for org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.lifecycle.api.LifecycleListenerRegistrar
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : lai_g$(...).getProviders is not a function
    at Unknown.TypeError: lai_g$(Unknown@-1)
    at Unknown.Xfi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@21:82497)
    at Unknown.egi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@27:82593)
    at Unknown.dgi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@15:82584)
    at Unknown.bgi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@22:82566)
    at Unknown.cgi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@26:82572)
    at Unknown.agi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@24:82553)
    at Unknown.Xgi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@31:82860)
    at Unknown.oji_g$(erraiapp-0.js@12:83032)
    at Unknown.nji_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:83028)
    at Unknown.RDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@64:90298)
    at Unknown.Oji_g$(erraiapp-0.js@29:83183)
    at Unknown.Nji_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:83163)
    at Unknown.dhi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@17:82919)
    at Unknown.oji_g$(erraiapp-0.js@235:83032)
    at Unknown.NDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@20:90266)
    at Unknown.JFi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@24:90841)
    at Unknown.n_i_g$(erraiapp-0.js@16:91489)
    at Unknown.m_i_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:91449)
    at Unknown.uDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@27:90119)
    at Unknown.mDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@12:89902)
    at Unknown.YDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@24:90353)
    at Unknown.dhi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@17:82919)
    at Unknown.PGi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@223:91245)
    at Unknown.pDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@30:90073)
    at Unknown.qDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:90086)
    at Unknown.sDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:90099)
    at Unknown.rDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:90091)
    at Unknown.gDi_g$(erraiapp-0.js@10:89962)
    at Unknown.k0i_g$(erraiapp-0.js@24:61969)
    at Unknown.l0i_g$(erraiapp-0.js@8:61963)
    at Unknown.t0i_g$(erraiapp-0.js@24:62021)
    at Unknown.lambda_0_g$(erraiapp-0.js@27:103)
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [SyncBeanManager] Looked up 1 beans: [[type=org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.lifecycle.impl.LifecycleListenerRegistrarImpl, qualifiers=[@Default, @Any]]]
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [Create] Create page shown!
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:05:49 FINE [Navigation] URL value changed to Create
```

Just to point out the pattern that all these errors happen between the following stages of page lifecycle

```
[Navigation] Navigating to Create at url: Create
{error when looking up JsType providers for page Create }
PostConstruct for Create page
PageHiding for the previous page called Dash
{error when looking up JsType providers for LifecycleListenerRegistrar}
{error when looking up JsType providers for LifecycleListenerRegistrar}
PageShown for Create page
```

Navigating to the other page called Dash, will just repeat the same pattern of error.

Not sure if this has something to do with above. But during initial loading/bootstrapping. I get this error too!

```
13:47:27 FINE [Container] Bean manager initialized in 116ms
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:7913:47:27 FINE [Container] Running post initialization runnables...
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:7913:47:27 FINE [Container] All post initialization runnables finished in 0ms
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:8313:47:27 INFO [Container] IOC bootstrapper successfully initialized in 239ms
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:83 13:47:27 INFO [InitVotes] wait for: org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFramework
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:83 13:47:27 INFO [InitVotes] vote for: org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFramework
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:83 13:47:27 INFO [ClientMessageBus] bus initialization started ...
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:83 13:47:27 INFO [InitVotes] wait for: org.jboss.errai.bus.client.api.ClientMessageBus
***Throwable.java:121 Uncaught Error: java.lang.ClassCastException
    at drb_g$.oC_g$ [as createError_0_g$] (Throwable.java:121)
    at drb_g$.yC_g$ [as initializeBackingError_0_g$] (Throwable.java:113)
    at drb_g$.fC_g$ (Throwable.java:61)
    at drb_g$.LC_g$ (Exception.java:25)
    at drb_g$.TC_g$ (RuntimeException.java:25)
    at drb_g$ (ClassCastException.java:23)
    at c7g_g$ (InternalPreconditions.java:141)
    at m7g_g$ (InternalPreconditions.java:129)
    at d6d_g$ (Cast.java:75)
    at Array.h9d_g$ (my_00046devs_00046web_00046ErraiAppJUnit__EntryMethodHolder.java:3)
    at initializeModules_0_g$ (ModuleUtils.java:44)
    at Qbc_g$ (Impl.java:239)
    at Tbc_g$ (Impl.java:298)
    at Impl.java:77
    at B8d_g$ (ModuleUtils.java:55)
    at NodeList.java:23
oC_g$ @ Throwable.java:121
yC_g$ @ Throwable.java:113
fC_g$ @ Throwable.java:61
LC_g$ @ Exception.java:25
TC_g$ @ RuntimeException.java:25
drb_g$ @ ClassCastException.java:23
c7g_g$ @ InternalPreconditions.java:141
m7g_g$ @ InternalPreconditions.java:129
d6d_g$ @ Cast.java:75
h9d_g$ @ my_00046devs_00046web_00046ErraiAppJUnit__EntryMethodHolder.java:3
initializeModules_0_g$ @ ModuleUtils.java:44
Qbc_g$ @ Impl.java:239
Tbc_g$ @ Impl.java:298
(anonymous) @ Impl.java:77
B8d_g$ @ ModuleUtils.java:55
(anonymous) @ NodeList.java:23***
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:83 13:47:27 INFO [ClientMessageBus] sending handshake message to remote bus
ErraiConsoleLogHandler.java:79 13:47:27 FINEST [HttpPollingHandler] [bus] HttpPollingHandler.transmit([CommandType=Asso
```

I am completely lost. Appreciate any help!

Note: I am running this using Eclipse GWT stuff which is the embedded jetty server. Not wildfly or jboss.